# Is it possible to play and use HEIF/HEVC files on iOS 9 and 10?

Tags: ios, ios11, hevc, heif

Is it possible to play and use HEIF/HEVC files on iOS 9 and 10 using some kind of library, player or something? or is this something exclusively for iOS 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In June 2017, Apple announced support for HEIF in macOS High Sierra and iOS 11 which were released in September 2017. So, you can not use HEIF/HEVC in ios 9 and 10 or in macOS prior to Sierra!

Reference : [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT207022) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) !

Comment: OK, but I was wondering if a library was available to allow that on older devices. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! How any library can do this if iOS is not allowing this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this library which provides a pure software decoding of HEIF images. However it might consume a lot of RAM to read the HEIF on older devices making them running out of memory: https://swiftpackageindex.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageHEIFCoder